# Kendall W for continuous data

Tags: nonparametric, kendall-tau, concordance

Simple question: can I use the Kendall W test for continuous data? Cuz I used it for a bunch of continuous variables and almost all coefficients are very close to 1, with p-values very very very small (like they are all significant even after Bonferroni correction)

5 raters and ~ 150 blocks

using irr::kendall